# New Magento theme wont load theme styles

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, css

I have installed a new Magento install on my local machine and have given it a new theme. I updated the theme in the Config section in the admin, but the CSS for the theme is not being loaded. Instead, the css files in skin/frontend/base are being loaded. How can I change the folder from base to ?

The path to my theme is skin/frontend/. The only thing I have changed in the admin has been at System -> Conficuration -> Design and under the Package dropdown, I changed default to

Comment: Could you provide more details plz?
The path to the theme (skin) and what you changed in system config.

Comment: @ToonVanDooren done. See above

Comment: Is the folder after the package name named default?
+ did you try to clear cache?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be talking about two different things.
In Magento, there are

```
a) packages
b) themes
```

The package defines the first folder and the theme the underlying "child" folder.
An example:

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME
```

Furthermore, you can specify a separate folder for your skin via the backend settings, but it will be in the same package that you configured.

So, say you put `package = mycompany` and `theme = mytheme` and `skin = myskin`,

then your paths will be:

```
app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/template -> for phtml files
app/design/frontend/mycompany/mytheme/layout   -> for layout xml files, e.g. local.xml
skin/frontend/mycompany/myskin                 -> for skin files like css, js, images
```

Comment: I got confused between packages and themes.  Had the package created but didn't copy the skin directory for my new them

Comment: In this example, how woud you set the theme settings? In System > Configuration > Design, only the "Current Package Name" from 'default' to 'mycompany'?